# How do I left align part of the equation, while centre aligning the rest?

Tags: align, amsmath

I want to try recreate this, nothing in the `begin{align*}` environment has worked for me.

[image: Binomial Expansion]

Answer (score 8):

Solution for Plain TeX:

```
$$
  \vbox{\halign{\hfil$#{}$&\hfil$#$\hfil\cr
(a+b)^0 =& 1 \cr
(a+b)^1 =& a+b \cr
(a+b)^2 =& a^2+2ab+b^2 \cr
(a+b)^3 =& a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3 \cr
(a+b)^4 =& a^4+4a^3b+6a^2b^2+4ab^3+b^4 \cr
(a+b)^5 =& a^5+5a^4b+10a^3b^2+10a^2b^3+5ab^4+b^5 \cr
  }}
$$
\bye
```

This code will work in LaTeX too because it is based only on TeX primitives `\vbox`, `\halign`, `\hfil`, `\cr`.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{r@{}c}
(a+b)^0={} & 1 \\
(a+b)^1={} & a+b \\
(a+b)^2={} & a^2+2ab+b^2 \\
(a+b)^3={} & a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3 \\
(a+b)^4={} & a^4+4a^3b+6a^2b^2+4ab^3+b^4 \\
(a+b)^5={} & a^5+5a^4b+10a^3b^2+10a^2b^3+5ab^4+b^5
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`IEEEeqnarray`](https://moser-isi.ethz.ch/docs/typeset_equations.pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCc}
(a+b)^0 &=& 1 \\
(a+b)^1 &=& a+b \\
(a+b)^2 &=& a^2+2ab+b^2 \\
(a+b)^3 &=& a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3 \\
(a+b)^4 &=& a^4+4a^3b+6a^2b^2+4ab^3+b^4 \\
(a+b)^5 &=& a^5+5a^4b+10a^3b^2+10a^2b^3+5ab^4+b^5
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This version uses `\mathmakebox` (mathtools package).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\begin{document}

\savebox{\tempbox}{$\displaystyle a^5+5a^4b+10a^3b^2+10a^2b^3+5ab^4+b^5$}% widest entry

\begin{align*}
(a+b)^0 &= \mathmakebox[\wd\tempbox]{1} \\
(a+b)^1 &= \mathmakebox[\wd\tempbox]{a+b} \\
(a+b)^2 &= \mathmakebox[\wd\tempbox]{a^2+2b+b^2} \\
(a+b)^3 &= \mathmakebox[\wd\tempbox]{a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3} \\
(a+b)^4 &= \mathmakebox[\wd\tempbox]{a^4+4a^3b+6a^2b^2+4ab^3+b^4} \\
(a+b)^5 &= \usebox\tempbox
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```